# Trying to Determine if a Cell is equal to a Value using Range, get runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
With wbImportFile.Sheets(1)
    .Range(Cells(iFirstRow + 464, iFirstColumn)).Select
    If Not Selection.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("This cam has an offset")
    End If
End With
```

All, I am trying to determine if a specific cell in a file I am importing has a value in it.  wbImportFile is a Workbook variable, and iFirstRow and iFirstColumn are Long variable (calculated in previous code).

I'm just trying to determine if the cell that is located at the iFirstRow + 464th row and iFirstColumn is empty, and when I do, I get an error on the second line that is runtime error 1004 "Application defined or object defined error."

I have also tried the code without the with statement:

```
If Not Range(Cells(iFirstRow + 464, iFirstColumn)).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("This cam has an offset")
End If
```

but I get the same error.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
With wbImportFile.Sheets(1)
    If Not .Cells(iFirstRow + 464, iFirstColumn).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "This cam has an offset"
    End If
End With
```

You can use `Range` object like this `Range("A1:A10")` or `Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(10,1))`, but you can't use `Range` object in that way: `.Range(Cells(..))`. You should simply use `.Cells()` instead.

Comment: +1 But I would add that you **can** use `.Cells` with `.Range`, just not like the OP did. Example: `.Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(10,2))`

Comment: @ARich, thanks:) you're right, it's exactly the thing I'm trying to tell OP:)

Comment: @ARich Wow, what confusing rules.

Comment: It can be sometimes. :) Technically, your code probably would have worked if you had added `.Address` to the end of `.Cells`. Example: `.Range(.Cells(iFirstRow + 464, iFirstColumn).Address)`.

Comment: Okay guys, I am still having trouble understanding this whole Range, Cells thing.  I have "Answered my own question" with more code below.